# Finding the common tangents to the parabola $y^2=15x$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=16$

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

[image]

I'm fine with part i, need help with part ii.
And given that the normal to the tangent is y=-1/m.

Comment: What have you tried

Comment: The dual conics are $16X^2+16Y^2=1$ and $15X-(225Y^2)/4=0.$ They intersect in $(\frac{3}{20},\pm\frac15),(-\frac{5}{12},\pm \frac{i}{3}).$ This means that two of the four common tangents are real: $\frac{3}{20}x\pm\frac15 y+1=0.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Once you already know that $y=mx+15/4m$ is tangent to the parabola. It is just necessary to put it tangent to the circle. On way to do that is replace that value of $y$ into the circle equation:

$$x^2+\left(mx+\frac{15}{4m}\right)^2=16$$

It will give you a quadradic equation and you have to force it to have only one solution.

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

By your work the equation of the tangent it's:
$$mx-y+\frac{15}{4m}=0$$ and since the distance from the center of the circle and the tangent is equal to the radius of the circle, we obtain:
$$\frac{\left|m\cdot0-0+\frac{15}{4m}\right|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}=4,$$ which gives $m=\frac{3}{4}$ or $m=-\frac{3}{4}.$

Can you end it now?

Comment: This is the problem I am having. I am unsure where you have gotten that second part.

Comment: @Cuddly I added something. See now.

Comment: Note that the perpendicular distance of a point($x_1,y_1$) to a line is given by $\frac{ax_1+by_1+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ for the line $ax+by +c$. Also note that this shortest distance is the radius when the line is a tangent to a circle and the point the center of the circle

Comment: Yep, I understand how to get the answer from that. But how did you obtain that equation.

Comment: @Cuddly  $(x_1,y_1)$ it's $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yep, thank I understand now. Thanks all.